# Is there a way to flip the border image on the left side only?

Tags: css

Is there a way to reverse the border-image on just the left side of the page so that the straight edge of the lace is to the center of the page like the right side?

Screenshot:

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/iQXLarNnWBe0CrIxKnZzhJMWHgMv3UISDqUuJv6B-NTbaSD3pJxycC0bKbgAe7lIsDfhmBnAS9sj_eAs4xNLFnME5egX3xEUpZxw3FNU46eeM_bpZucTOlZ2Uu0900mUS9e3jZ5ac5ePzfQl4W_i-iDZyP0QWurxKyeaP1cR-6WEcnpaCSUJofEjqEBEOjv5fLed5GTaLTklhLwEFvAdEnoIqwQigV3I0ZD6EYwpO1G6dNza6ejc8xVTkf294XUhkHxSQSovyj3IWif6Yfp3RyXflCwYZ7aMXL657WM7n3QxTve7YEZR68f_yq9rl8p8VUfyuwvUej1Rna43rl5fbN51vL33XUPQ5Q1Du0gA62Q2uxXzE-xy0fQWJixGl6xgQvHuECHM2sLQbYg3w_PHY8WTNIgTfcNoCIXSCobBS8zEBOO5q-iJRywvl631--KpYEQHQ_9APodsX0M0sRupMOIXiLdrHWvEcEd-yQ4g5t5oBagU3Cx6Pti37WlO_P4YTdp-virl8XTpZyFZeCy5cFpfGVuKNcVzEfWjfsQ6-bvkJhc1x7d3PWYPIZ7hUcM9pYPniy1Sx7P-VxZe-Vs-GWJzyh_BmXgS6-JuW8YLA4m4aO2V6nlz1QIkZS55BK0KMzAMYZi48evlzLIVZf2veuBjA8w5P2ROT-nETga2gnEnI10S1aZ495BcgwfPCkCOryTtxI5HilIsf1ULOSZsqjvn=w1277-h523-no

I have done quite a bit of online searching but I have not seen any solutions to this problem.

css file:

```
div.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 75%;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 0 76px;
    border-image: 76 repeat url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/o-AmkgUtE-j5QcXB96gMQt80O4UxaDxMiP2En4imiWnF9ZN363dlePAyJRpeJvhQJWjUmRSp9wxKAnyW3AZsKsSmAy4NVD1ROnZ8LXMnT8-JcGac5ch9YXuyyRiyLOhTk5JJynfd8LKMVCg3VnQKAiXoT2CWrB8UHLNEUNcng1YLOyWN9k56q5n3vb8trNtv67SrANk77IiFpoM8_N0eu1i7zkqtk_kI2cxwwUn85dvHt42IkKzC1Q1TVNrG1cJ0-FKRaT9APUf3yGh79p423Zn-p6RCz2oeqT1uUu2qrVrVdn58betT27ROxrEjIhryCOTjsI4_A_IK9Zy5O4GJ7Y92DCNe1Ug18eetmFGMxW6eyuZJ9MkqXrGH1dCv43dJYWQNYjn7N-dB63DeDCf3P6X_ARUKS_lKZfSPyazlBRAPrBVvFaIu8RXJh3bdM0SfSR6SIOuy4Wzo_8DF8rHZ71YJMq9yQ7yE4Eend3VsFqan2jasLpQd2oUN-dE82QUs6v2PoOynQhVqkUDe5AkIKn4BGX1YnoqImLRMUVYzYN0WVx-ikxEWgDVTnYU9PqK5D41ePIyTdNNq3BLB2s-5RMqyaILGageeZhE2Mv14_QYyY5-PQpYK-pvBG6iKNBEZc91cDYXSnuVKBeV8j5hYE00HAJYm3hiIuux23JwUC5POkIkzXDNJcV06Wr_FdNc5__FiWEPe39ANlRpgx4KWB7fJ=w76-h320-no);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using psudeo ::before ::after and flipping the image using transform there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flipping image is done by `transform`

```
-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
```

Hope this help.

Comment: How can this be applied to only the left border-image? That is what I'm stumped by.

Comment: Apply the image, then flip the image. You can do experiment and testing right?

Comment: OK i will give a hint, you can use a before and after in your div.

Comment: Ah! I was able to get it to work using :before and :after. Thank you so much!